# A weird rendering bug in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

> ## updates
>
> If the first time you load [the page](http://www.arch0-0.com/) and this bug doesn't occur,
>
> Click the [image: anchor] which directs you to the home page again, and the bug would most likely show up. (It is annoying that almost every time I go back to the home page from another pages, there is this bug.)
>
> I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.57.

---

Chrome has always been one of the greatest browsers that support CSS3. I was quite disappointed when I encountered this weird behavior of hers that resembles a bug.

I have handcrafted some [simple circular buttons with CSS3 and jQuery](http://www.arch0-0.com/). (I didn't go for pure Javascript because I was lazy to work on the crossbrowser compatibility myself.)

A button basically consists of one division containing two sub divisions and one sub division also contains another sub division. And they are all inside an anchor that triggers a window to superimpose:

```
<a><div class="archbox smaller"><div class="archfacebook"></div>
<div class="archrollerx"><div class="archfacebook below2"></div></div></div></a>
```

the anchor is simply styled to `flow:right` and this is how the exterior division is styled:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 22px;
border-radius: 22px;
height: width: 44px;
height: 44px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px #FFF solid;
position: relative;
```

When nothing goes wrong, this is how they would look at a rest stage:

[image]

But sometimes when I load the page, this occurs:

[image]

But after the button had been moused-over, it turned normal again. (As if you just told Chrome that there was a bug.)

It went on normal for a while, but after some time, it occured again.

And sometimes it gives the extra border when moused-over:

[image]

This is really a weird behavior because it is not like run-time errors that occur everytime a page is loaded. Sometimes it would occur, while sometimes it simply would not. So I feel the need to fix it.

At first I thought there is some bug with the border, so I added this:

```
border:1px #FFF solid!important;
```

to the normal, hover and visited state of the buttons. But it didn't fix the problem; it still occurred every so often. I was really frustrated. After thinking about it or a while, I finally came to the realisation that there is actually a bug with the displacement: it seems like Chrome has the tendency to "subconsciously" display the Facebook & Twitter button again behind the Twitter and Google plus button, giving the illusion that they has a border. And I have no idea how to stop Chrome from behaving this way.

Has anyone encountered the same problem before? What should I do such that this won't happen at all?

I tried Firefox and Safari, and I had not yet encountered this.

Comment: Chrome is full of regressions when it comes to CSS (whether it be CSS2.1 or CSS3). You have been warned :)

Comment: I thought it was the best browser of all time..

Comment: all browsers suck in their own special way...

Comment: i know it can sounds odd but...you have any plugin that may cause this problem? Sounds like that because the problem, like you said, solved in private.

Comment: @Ark I didn't install any plug in. It is really weird that private solves the problem. My current chrome seems to have something that triggers the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I reloaded the page many times, also used the private browsing to avoid if cached, haven't encountered this bug. Google Chrome 24.0.1312.57 m, Windows 7 Ultimate 64b.

Does your Google Chrome perhaps load some resources from the cache?

Comment: That is weird.. After clearing my cache it still occurs. But when I use private browsing I don't encounter this bug. I think I need to do a survey with my friends and see if anyone of them experience the same thing I experience.

Comment: +1 I think we are heading to the right direction. Very likely a weird cache bug.

Comment: You may want to check by if any cache is still existent; hit the developer tools of Google Chrome and change to Network tab, then load your website see which if any are loaded from the cache.

Comment: After clearing the previous cache I load the page again, there is no cache and no bug. But the second time I load it the bug occurs.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

```
<a class="con archtwitterx" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=+check+this+article+ out&amp;url=http%3A%2F/www.arch0-0.com/2013/02/why-i-chose-to-drop-out.html" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,   '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=800');return false;" target="_parent" style="
    border: 0;
">
```

style="border: 0;" on a fixed it

---

```
outline: 0;
```

might do the trick.  but my guess is on border.

Comment: can you put your code on a fiddle so i can play with ita nd try to help you out? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I don't think jsfiddle.net would provide a solution in this case. It is not a normal CSS3 or Js bug.

Comment: teh fiddle is not to provide teh solution but to be able to see and chaneg yoru code while looking for a solution.